# Problem with using dojoAttachpoint while adding /removing style

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a div as show below:

```
<div id="xyz" dojoAttachPoint="xyz" style="display: none;">  </div>
```

Now I want to show/ hide it. If I do it using dojo.byID it works. But if I do it using dojoAttachppoint it does not work properly. I don't get any errors but changes don't take place.

```
dojo.byId("xyz").style.display="none";
dojo.byId("xyz").style.display="";


this.xyz.style.display ="none";
this.xyz.style.display ="";
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: So, this is in the template of a widget mixing in `_Templated`?  I ask since that's the only place where `dojoAttachPoint`s are parsed/hooked up.

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to dojoAttachPoint.

Comment: @Ken : yes there is a template and corresponding js file

Comment: @STephen : It is relatedto attachpoint.The problem is when we use attachPoint on a widget we get a reference to the object not the node, so we need to use domnode property like this.xyz.domNode.style.display= "none " , but using  this am getting error saying this.xyz.domNode is undefined

Comment: @dojoX, I suggest that you revise your question by giving more information, such as you are declaring a dijit class with dojo.declare, based on dijit._Templated, and using dojoAttachPoint to attach the element to the dijit class.

Comment: @dojoX, also see my other comment below.  "dojoAttachPoint" is used to create a property in the dijit object that points to the **DOM element** (i.e. your div).  It does **not** point to a widget object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the above in a template within a class declared using `dojo.declare` with base class `dijit._Templated`?

Your understanding of attach points is flaky. When `dijit._Templated` parses the tenmplate, and when it sees a "dojoAttachPoint" attribute, it will create a property in the dijit object with the attach point's name. Therefore, "xyz" is a property in the dijit class object. The name is taken from the attribute called "dojoAttachPoint" when the template is being read. The dojoAttachPoint attribute is no longer used afterwards.

If "this" points to the dijit class you created, `this.xyz` will point to the **DOM element** (i.e. the div), never a widget. Therefore it does **not** have a "domNode" property. Trace the source code in `dijit/_Templated.js line#191` to confirm.

Therefore, you need to do some `console.log` calls to confirm that `this.xyz` is returning the correct div. If it does, then you can try `dojo.style(this.xyz, "display", "none")` to see if you can hide it etc.

As to why `this.xyz.style.display = "none"` won't work, it may be a browser-specific thing, as it should do the same thing as `dojo.style`.  You'll need to dig deeper to find out.

Comment: @Stephen : xyz in not property .It is dojoAttachpoint.So my code is this.myAttachpoint.style.display or this.myAttachpoint.domNode.style.display

Comment: dojo.byId("xyz")  is just replace with this.xyz ,where xyz is a attachpoint. Also i have tried using this.xyz.innerHTML and it works

Comment: In that case, you're using the above in a template within a class declared using `dojo.declare` with base class `dijit._Templated`?  Why didn't you say so in your question?

Comment: Your understanding of attach points is flaky.  When dijit._Templated parses the tenmplate, and when it sees a `dojoAttachPoint`, it will create a property in the class with the attach point's name.  Therefore, "xyz" is a property in the dijit class that you declared.  The name is taken from the attribute called "dojoAttachPoint" when the template is being read.  The dojoAttachPoint attribute is no longer used afterwards.

Comment: If "this" points to the dijit class you created, this.xyz will point to the **DOM element** (i.e. the div), never a widget.  Therefore it does **not** have a "domNode" property.  Trace the source code in dijit/_Templated.js line#191 to confirm.

Comment: Therefore, you need to do some console.log calls to confirm that `this.xyz` is returning the correct div.  If it does, then you can try `dojo.style(this.xyz, "display", "none")` to see if you can hide it etc.

Comment: @Stephen : dojo.style(this.xyz, "display", "none")  worked .Thanks

Comment: @dojoX, I am copying down these comments and editing my answer.  Just so that people won't downvote me for answering the wrong thing.